# How to identify index intervals that contain a value?

Tags: dataset, intervals, indexing

I have a really simple question but, sorry, I can't seem to find an elegant solution to other than iterating through. I have a list of indices, and a relative list of values, I would like to extract lists of intervals that contain the value 1.

For example say, IndexList = {1,5,10,12}
Data = {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}

What I would like to get is 
{{1,5},{10,12}} or the intervals within the previous list that contained 1.

NOTE: For clarification, I am looking for all those intervals in which the relative list contains 1. The backstory is this is to try filtering data from a time series to extract positive examples to feed them to ML.

Comment: How do you expect an outcome to occur when you have only one 1? I would think from your initial explanation you'd want only a single value in the list? Or is it that you would be searching such that it goes "Is there a value 1 between 1,5? 5,10? 10,12?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
Split[IndexList, Total[Data[[# ;; #2]]] >= 1 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {10, 12}}
> ```

Also

```
Split[IndexList, MemberQ[Data[[# ;; #2]], 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {10, 12}}
> ```

Comment: Actually, this is trickier than I expected. To get pairwise groupings to work right you need a function that evaluates differently across the pairs. In practice, I've found this doesn't work with more general lists of 0 and 1 data. If there were many 1's in the data field the output will be just a list of all the indeces separate.

Answer (score 2):

With help from Kglr's answer, I worked out what I was looking for.

For the computation to work with arbitrary sequence of 0 and 1's I found I needed to explicitly identify all pairs of indices.

I am sure this is not the most elegant or concise, but it seems to work.

```
IndexList  = {1, 5, 10, 12};
Data = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
ValidRanges = MemberQ[Data[ [#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]] ], 1.] & /@ 
 Partition[Sort[Join[IndexList, IndexList]][[2 ;; -1 ]], 2]
ValidData = Data[ [#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]] ] & /@ 
 Partition[Sort[Join[IndexList, IndexList]][[2 ;; -1 ]], 2]
```